# Powershell remoting error from docker container to Windows Server 2019 and 2022

Tags: docker, powershell, powershell-remoting

Morning,

I have been attempting to Powershell remote from a Linux docker container to a Windows Server 2019 or 2022 box. Its worth noting that both OS are not part of a domain.

On the Host I have set the trusted hosts to *

```
Get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts


Type            Name                           SourceOfValue   Value
----            ----                           -------------   -----
System.String   TrustedHosts                                   *
```

I understand the security risk but this is a test bed environment, the hosts would be more restricted in Production.

On the docker container image CLI.

I initiate Powershell via

```
pwsh
```

I am then try following command from the Linux docker container:

```
PS/>Enter-PSSession -ComputerName server2019 -Credential $Cred -Authentication Negotiate
```

OR

```
PS/>New-PSSession -ComputerName server2019 -Credential $Cred -Authentication Negotiate
```

I am then prompted for a username and password in which I manually enter. I have validated the username and password multiple times and made them simple to ensure that I cannot get them wrong.

Note - For testing the username is 'Admin' and the password is 'Password!'.

I am presented with the following error:

```
Enter-PSSession: Connecting to remote server server2019 failed with the following error message : MI_RESULT_ACCESS_DENIED For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic
```

I have also setup SSH on the server and clients to attempt to connect via SSH for Powershell remoting.

```
PS/>Enter-PSSession -HostName server2019 -UserName admin
```

The error returned is:

```
Enter-PSSession: The background process reported an error with the following message: The SSH client session has ended with error message: subsystem request failed on channel 0
```

I have test the above from a Windows 10 & 11 Desktop machines and have no issues to connect.

What's strange that if install Powershell on the docker host (Ubuntu 20.04) via the
[Micrsoft Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/install-ubuntu?view=powershell-7.2), it connects fine but not from the docker container.

### Information about Docker container

**Image** : mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim

**Packages installed**: iputils-ping,net-tools,gss-ntlmssp,apt-transport-https,software-properties-common,openssh-client,powershell

Note I can also ping the server successfully from the docker container. I can also SSH to the server after installing the SSHserver on the 2019 server.

```
ssh admin@server2019
```

From the docker container:

```
PS/>$psversiontable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.2.0
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.2.0
OS                             Linux 5.4.0-90-generic #101-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 15 20:00:55 UTC 2021
Platform                       Unix
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

My conclusion is that the issue is due to the docker container.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this?

Comment: Yes i rebuilt my ubuntu image and everything worked fine, guess I had an issue with the OS. It was quicker to just rebuild the OS.

Comment: OK I will try from 22.04 as so far I've only tried with earlier releases. If you have any tricks or guides to get removing working I would love to hear them :)